# Rename photo taken Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I created an application and in this app I take a photo with an expo-camera and save it with MediaLibrary, but I can't rename the photo. How can I rename the photo? I tried to use String.slice and change the name at the end of the uri, but it doesn't work because to use String.slice uri has to be created before the photo is taken.

How i take the photo:

```
 takePicture = async () => {
        if (this.camera) {
          let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
          this.setState({
            image: photo.uri,
            modalOpen: true
          });
        }
        console.log(this.state.image)
      }
```

How i save:

```
saveImage = async (image, imageName) => {

    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(image);
    MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Geocad', asset)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Album created!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('err', error);
      });
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false
    });
  }
```

What i try:

```
        var str = image;
        var indices = [];
        for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
            if (str[i] === "/") indices.push(i);
        }
        let indexNameSlice = indices.slice(-1,)[0]

        let oldImageName = image.slice(0,indexNameSlice)
        let newImageName = oldImageName+'/'+imageName+'.jpg'
        console.log('NEWIMAGENAME', newImageName+'/'+imageName+'.jpg')

        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(newImageName);
```

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question.

Comment: I Already added

Comment: @ChrisG any idea?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?